# Store array in session variable and post the session variable into another page

Tags: php, session

This is my code in 1st page,

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dataconnection.php';
$res = mysql_query("select * from questions where category_id=1 LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

echo $rows;

while ($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++)
    {           
        $_SESSION['questions']=$result;

    }
    echo implode("",$_SESSION['questions']);

}
?>
```

In next page my code

```
<?php    
session_start();    
echo implode(",",$_SESSION['questions']);
?>
```

Comment: add next page code and the error you are getting on the next page

Comment: And the purpose of that `for` loop? It has no effect but useless execution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code doesn't add to an array, but overwrite the value in it. It simply sets $_SESSION['questions'] to the same value as $result x times, where x is the number of rows.

```
while ($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++)
  {           
    $_SESSION['questions']=$result;
  }
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
while ($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {         
    $_SESSION['questions'][]=$result;
}
```

Comment: it gives error in next page "Notice: Array to string conversion in"

Comment: i am also used impload(" ",$_session['questions]);

Comment: each row is an array in itself, so you have an array of arrays. if you want to simply verify that the data is there, use `print_r($_SESSION['questions'])` instead of implode. If it is important for you to use implode, you'll instead need to implode each row before adding it to the session variable: `$_SESSION['questions'][]=implode(","$result);`

Comment: thank you sir,its working but it gives only static values i want dynamic values..means i develop a quiz application. i want to store the record in session variable as array when user click next button. up to user click finish button and all those array values post to next page with selected radio option of the user